# Rails: Optimizing queries to database for has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

In my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :received_messages 
             :foreign_key => 'recipient_id        
end
```

In the index action of my messages controller, I have: 
`@messages = current_user.received_messages`

In my view (shorter version of actual code):

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
    <%= message.sender.full_name %><br>
    <%= truncate(message.body, :length => 50) %>
<%end%>
```

The issue is that for every message, it will query the database for the message sender. SO if there are 20 messages, it will  send 20 requests to the database. How do I avoid that? I have been reading about Eager loading and `:includes`, but I don't know how to apply it in this instance.

Note that sender is just another instance of the User class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is [eager loading associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations), with the method `includes` :

```
@messages = current_user.received_messages.includes(:sender)
```